# WordPress: Disable "Add New" on Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to disable the option of adding a new post under a Custom Post Type in WordPress (3.0)? I've looked into labels and arguments but can't find anything that would resemble such a feature.

Comment: Talk about digging up the dead - I stumbled back here today & I can see Seamus' answer, you should consider marking it as accepted, it's definitely the "right" one.

Answer (score 133):

There is a meta capability `create_posts` that is [documented here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and is used by WordPress to check before inserting the various 'Add New' buttons and links. In your custom post type declaration, add `capabilities` (not to be confused with `cap`) and then set it to `false` as below.

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false, // Removes support for the "Add New" function ( use 'do_not_allow' instead of false for multisite set ups )
  ),
  'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts
));
```

You'll probably want to set `map_meta_cap` to `true` as well. Without it, you won't be able to access the posts' editing pages anymore.

Comment: Had to +1 this as well.  It will certainly remove the ability to add a new cpt.. but it also removes much more.  Perfect for extreme lockdown.. but I needed a few functions this also removes.  Still, a great answer!  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that Josh. Would you mind sharing what other functionality it also locked down so everyone else also is aware?

Comment: This will also remove the read/edit/trash functions. The user can only see the list of posts but not open or edit anything. To allow users to edit existing posts you also have to add the option `'map_meta_cap' => true`

Comment: @SeamusLeahy Would it be possible to disable adding new posts only when there are already 3 posts for example?

Comment: Instead of setting `create_posts` to `false` you can set it to another capability such as `administrator` to only allow certain roles to create posts.

Comment: I had to change the snippet to `'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'` to [make it work for multisite setups](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1046) - but nevertheless thank's for the insights!

Comment: what if you're using a plugin (i.e. Types) to create the custom post type?

Comment: 'create_posts' => false no longer works in WP4.5. I solved this by using 'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow' (a non-existing capability) instead @seamus-leahy, perhaps you'd like to update your answer?

Comment: Works perfectly for administrator. I need my subscribers to be able to edit their existing posts but it disables them even from viewing posts' page. Any solution?

Comment: @MohammadHosseinR, there is a bug in WordPress that causes users without the `edit_posts` capability to be denied permission to the list page when the **Add New** button is removed in this way. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218457/wordpress-user-with-custom-role-cannot-view-list-page-for-custom-post-types-with

Comment: @MohammadHosseinR, I just posted another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218457/wordpress-user-with-custom-role-cannot-view-list-page-for-custom-post-types-with

Answer (score 13):

The combinations of the solutions above work in hiding the links (although someone could quite easily type the URL in directly.

The [solution mentioned @3pepe3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916356/248567) relies on `get_post_type()` which will only work if there is already a post in the listing. If there are no posts, the function will not return anything, and the "Add New" link will be available. An alternative method:

```
function disable_new_posts() {
    // Hide sidebar link
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=CUSTOM_POST_TYPE'][10]);

    // Hide link on listing page
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE') {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        #favorite-actions, .add-new-h2, .tablenav { display:none; }
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_new_posts');
```

EDIT: To prevent direct access if someone types the URL in themselves: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58292/6003

Answer (score 9):

**Disable creating new post for registered post-types:** (example for `post` and `page`)

```
function disable_create_newpost() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['post']->cap->create_posts = 'do_not_allow';
    //$wp_post_types['page']->cap->create_posts = 'do_not_allow';
    //$wp_post_types['my-post-type']->cap->create_posts = 'do_not_allow';
}
add_action('init','disable_create_newpost');
```

Comment: Thank you - this is great. We are using this and targeting wp_block and using 'administrator' to stop non-admins from adding new synced patterns via wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp_block (what used to be reusable blocks until version 6.3)

Answer (score 8):

WordPress Networks: <s>I found that [Seamus Leahy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675677/1401426) doesn't work</s> if you are logged in as a super admin of the network, it doesn't matter if the user doesn't have the capability, mapped or otherwise, when current_user_can($cap) is called by the CMS. By digging into the core I found you can do the following.

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow', // Removes support for the "Add New" function, including Super Admin's
  ),
  'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to false, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts
));
```

<s>The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248103/1401426) hides the menu item, but the page is still accessible.</s>

Comment: this also prevents me from displaying the list of my custom post type. is there any solution for this?

Comment: This is definitely working!

Answer (score 7):

In wordpress and for all the post types there is the capability create_posts. This capability is used in several core files :

1. wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php
2. wp-admin\edit.php
3. wp-admin\includes\post.php
4. wp-admin\menu.php
5. wp-admin\post-new.php
6. wp-admin\press-this.php
7. wp-includes\admin-bar.php
8. wp-includes\class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php
9. wp-includes\post.php

So if you really want to disable this feautere you must do it per role and per post type.
I use the great plugin "[User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)" to manage the capabilities per role.

But what about the capability create_posts? Well this capability is not mapped and also create_posts is equal to create_posts so we should fix this and map the capability per post type.

So you can add this piece of code in your functions.php and the you can manage this capability.

```
function fix_capability_create(){
    $post_types = get_post_types( array(),'objects' );
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        $cap = "create_".$post_type->name;
        $post_type->cap->create_posts = $cap;
        map_meta_cap( $cap, 1); 
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'fix_capability_create',100);
```

So here we are not hiding or removing menu elements... here we are removing the capability for users (including xmlrpc requests).

The action was init and not admin_init or anything else because init at priority 100 prevents the display of "add new" on admin bar, sidebar, etc (in all the wp interface).

Answer (score 6):

```
add_action("load-post-new.php", 'block_post');

function block_post()
{
    if($_GET["post_type"] == "custom_type") 
        wp_redirect("edit.php?post_type=custom_type");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@ Staffan Estberg,

This is best way to hide the Add New or Create New button in custom postypes

```
'capability_type'    => 'post',

        'capabilities'       => array( 'create_posts' => false ),       

        'map_meta_cap'       => true,
```

It disable to create new post in custom post types both side in admin menu and above the list of post type.

Comment: Hi I want disable edit and move to trash/remove custom post type in  Wordpress 6.0.2 (admin should be able to create/publish, and everyone should be able to read). I try by `'delete_post'           => 'do_not_allow', 'edit_post'           => 'do_not_allow'` or false but it doesn't work, because it makes add new imposible too. Had you any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found this simplest way for this.  Just ad this code into theme’s `function.php`.

```
function hd_add_buttons() {
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin()) {
        if ($_GET['post_type'] == 'custom_post_type_name') {
            echo '<style>.add-new-h2{display: none !important;}</style>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hd_add_buttons');
```

Comment: Be aware, this simply hides the 'add new' button, it does not programmatically prevent users from adding new posts.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is 'how to disable add-new button on custom post type', and not 'how to restrict user editing custom post types', in my opinion the answer should be purely hiding the buttons with css, by adding this to the functions.php file :

```
add_action( 'admin_head', function(){
    ob_start(); ?>
    <style>
        #wp-admin-bar-new-content{
            display: none;
        }
        a.page-title-action{
            display: none !important;
        }
        #menu-posts-MY-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
<?php ob_end_flush();
});
```