# How to hide Add New custom post type button

Tags: wordpress, addition, custom-post-type

I want to hide admin side my custom type **Add New** button. Review this screen shot -> https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1406976/p6f5u0nlvs5xff3sr85h

So any one know solutions then please update me.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can't open your image - But if you want to remove something from the menu in the admin section - you can use : remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ); in your funcions

Comment: If it is only a submenu item, you can use : remove_submenu_page( $menu_slug, $submenu_slug );

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235257/wordpress-disable-add-new-on-custom-post-type

Comment: Not working above solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: Disable "Add New" on Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235257/wordpress-disable-add-new-on-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 1):

you can use meta capability `create_posts` that is not documented but is used by WordPress to check before inserting the various 'Add New' buttons and links. In your custom post type declaration, add `capabilities` (not to be confused with `cap`) and then set it to `false` as below.

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false, // Removes support for the "Add New" function ( use 'do_not_allow' instead of false for multisite set ups )
  ),
  'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts
));
```

Where `custom_post_type_name` you can put your custom post type name, which you are creating.