# How to remove "add new" button from the editor page of a custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named "jxta_home". I have removed add new button from the submenu and edit page by using the following code-

```
<?php
function disable_new_posts() {

    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=jxta_home'][10]);

    // Hide link on listing page
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'jxta_home')  {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        .page-title-action, .submitdelete { display:none; }
        </style>';
    } 
}
```

But the add new button is still showing on the inner editor page. I want to remove it from there too. How can I remove it from the inner editor page?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: Disable "Add New" on Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235257/wordpress-disable-add-new-on-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two option once is with css and another is will coding.

**Option 1 :**

```
function disable_new_posts() {
// Hide sidebar link
global $submenu;
unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=jxta_home'][10]);

// Hide link on listing page
if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'jxta_home') {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
    #favorite-actions, .add-new-h2, .tablenav { display:none; }
    </style>';
 }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_new_posts');
```

**Option 2** :

You disable the add new capabilities while passing the parameter in the register post type.

The parameter is :

> create_posts' => false

Assuming you have the code like below :

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'capability_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => false
    )
);
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type', $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can change the capabilities**

Register the post type with the *map_meta_cap* and *create_posts* as true;

```
$args = array(
     'label'               => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
     'description'         => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
     'capability_type' => 'custom_post_type',

     'map_meta_cap'=>true,
     'capabilities' => array(
         'create_posts' => true
     )
);
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type', $args );
```

Then You can change the capabilities adding an action on **load-post.php** tag.

```
add_action('load-post.php', 'remove_add_button');

function remove_add_button() {
   if( get_post_type($_GET['post']) == 'MY-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE' ) {
     global $wp_post_types;

     $wp_post_types['MY-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE']->map_meta_cap = true;
     $wp_post_types['MY-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE']->cap->create_posts = false;
   }
}
```