# Remove title & add new button from a custom post type - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

[image]

Need a solution to remove the "Title" and "Add new" button from a post type without jQuery.

Comment: when you create your custom post type, did you set it to support [title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#supports) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: Disable "Add New" on Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235257/wordpress-disable-add-new-on-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 0):

You  can disable the add new capabilities while passing the parameter in the register post type.

The parameter is :

> create_posts' => false

Assuming you have the code like below :

```
$args = array(
      'label' => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
      'capabilities' => array(
            'create_posts' => false
        )
);

register_post_type( 'custom_post_type', $args );
```

In order to remove the title I'm not sure if that is possible,
one solutions would be hiding using `css`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to remove the title is to use the function remove_post_type_support().

```
remove_post_type_support('custom_post_type', 'title');
```

You can add this to your functions.php file by calling it via the init hook.

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_custom_post_support' );

function remove_custom_post_support() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'custom_post_type', 'title' );
}
```