# WordPress user with custom role cannot view list page for custom post types without the "create_posts" capabililty

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-capabilities, wordpress-roles

I am running a WordPress 5.2.3 site and having trouble with something in the admin panel.

I have a custom role, let's call it `librarian`, and a custom post type, let's call it `book`.

I want to make it so that a `librarian` can edit a `book` but not create a new one.

Following the advice in another question ([WordPress: Disable “Add New” on Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235257/wordpress-disable-add-new-on-custom-post-type)) and [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), I have ended up with this code:

```php
// Custom post type.
register_post_type('book',
    array(
        'labels'                => array(
            'name' => __( 'book' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Book' )
        ),
        'capability_type'       => array('book', 'books'),
        'capabilities'          => array(
            'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow' // <-- The important bit.
        ),
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        'description'           => 'Book full of pages',
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-location',
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'supports'              => array('title', 'revisions')
    ));
```

```php
// Custom role.
add_role('librarian', 'Librarian', array(
    'read'                  => true,
    'edit_books'            => true,
    'edit_published_books'  => true
));
```

I was expecting that when I visited `edit.php?post_type=book` as a `librariran`then I would see the list of `books` for editing, but I would not see the **Add New** button. However, what I actually get is a `403` response:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

I think this may be a bug in WordPress, because of the following cases:

- If I visit `edit.php?post_type=book` as an `administrator`, then I see the list page without the **Add New** button, as desired.
- If I give the `librarian` role the `edit_posts` capability, then I see the list page without the **Add New** button, as desired (but I don't want to give them the `edit_posts` capability!).

These make me think that it isn't a problem with the custom post type set up in general.

- If I remove the `'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'` from the `book` type registration, the `librarian` *can* see the list page, but it includes the **Add New** button.

This makes me think that it isn't a problem with the custom role set up in general.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Have I missed anything from my configuration? Or is there an easy patch or workaround?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug in WordPress. I have found the source of the problem and a workaround.

## Workaround

If you're not interested in the cause, the workaround is to comment out this bit of cosmetic code in `wp-admin/includes/menu.php`:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L168

```
/*
 * If there is only one submenu and it is has same destination as the parent,
 * remove the submenu.
 */
if ( ! empty( $submenu[ $data[2] ] ) && 1 == count( $submenu[ $data[2] ] ) ) {
    $subs      = $submenu[ $data[2] ];
    $first_sub = reset( $subs );
    if ( $data[2] == $first_sub[2] ) {
        unset( $submenu[ $data[2] ] );
    }
}
```

This will mean that some menu items that previously didn't show a submenu now will (with a single item the same as the main menu item), but that is only a cosmetic UI change.

## Cause

For those of you that want to know the detail…

Accessing `edit.php?post_type=book` was failing this check in `wp-admin/includes/menu.php`:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L341

```php
if ( ! user_can_access_admin_page() ) {

    /**
     * Fires when access to an admin page is denied.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'admin_page_access_denied' );

    wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.' ), 403 );
}
```

The call to [`user_can_access_admin_page()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1998) calls through to [`get_admin_page_parent()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1796).

If the submenu has been removed, `get_admin_page_parent()` returns an empty parent which ultimately causes `user_can_access_admin_page()` to erroneously return `false` in the case of the `librarian` role (the `administrator` role passes for a different reason).

If the submenu is left in place, `get_admin_page_parent()` returns a non-empty parent and the access check proceeds correctly from there.

So the root issue is that the global `$submenu` is being used to both determine the UI and also to make decisions on the permissions hierarchy. I don't see an immediate quick fix for this problem that wouldn't have side effects elsewhere throughout the WordPress code, other than the workaround above.

Comment: I think I found a solution that doesn't require editing core files. Checkout my Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a workaround for this without having to edit the core files.

As you said, the cause of this bug is that a empty menu that has no sub-menu items will cause access check to erroneously return false.

So the workaround is to not make the list page a top-level menu. Instead, make it a sub-menu under an existing menu. This way there won't be an empty top-level menu and you can see the list page correctly without the 'Add New' button.

This is only a workaround, not ideal. But perhaps it's better than editing the core files.

The way to create a custom post type while putting its list page as a sub-menu item is simple. The args of `register_post_type` has an arg called `show_in_menu`. As [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) say:

> If a string of an existing top level menu (eg. 'tools.php' or 'edit.php?post_type=page'), the post type will be placed as a sub-menu of that.

So the code will be:

```
register_post_type('book',
array(
    'labels'                => array(
        'name' => __( 'book' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Book' )
    ),
    'capability_type'       => array('book', 'books'),
    'capabilities'          => array(
        'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'
    ),
    'map_meta_cap'          => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => 'tools.php',   //or whatever top-level menu you'd like
    //... other args omitted
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 Workarounds for this issue:

First off I find it better to assign a specific capability for the custom_post_type create_posts instead of using `do_not_allow`

So I use:

```
...
'capability_type'     => 'books',
'capabilities'        => array(
    'create_posts' => 'add_new_books'
),
'map_meta_cap'        => true,
...
```

This way I can assign Admins or other Managers the add_new_books capability, but don't allow it for other roles.

**Option 1**:
(Filter the user_has_cap to fake that the user has 'edit_posts' but then remove the Posts Menu Item)

```
add_filter(
    'user_has_cap',
    function( $all_caps, $caps ) {
        global $typenow, $menu;

        if ( is_admin() && ! empty( $typenow ) && stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'edit.php' ) && stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'post_type=' . $typenow ) && in_array( 'edit_posts', $caps, true ) ) {
            // Temporarily assign the user the edit_posts capability
            $all_caps['edit_posts'] = true;
            // Now Remove any menu items with edit_posts besides the custom post type pages.
            if ( ! empty( $menu ) ) {
                foreach ( $menu as $menu_key => $menu_item ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $menu_item[1] ) && ( $menu_item[1] === 'edit_posts' || $menu_item[2] === 'edit.php' ) ) {
                        remove_menu_page( $menu_item[2] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $all_caps;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

While this works it does add some PHP Notices for undefined indexes.

**Option 2**:
(Filter the $pagenow variable)

```
add_action(
    'admin_menu',
    function () {
        global $pagenow, $typenow;

        if ( is_admin() && ! empty( $typenow ) && ! empty( $pagenow ) && $pagenow === 'edit.php' && stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'edit.php' ) && stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'post_type=' . $typenow ) ) {
            $pagenow = 'custom_post_type_edit.php';
        }
    }
);
```

This works without adding any PHP Notices, but may have unforseen issues as it is changing the $pagenow variable, but only on that page.

So far I am using Option 2 without any issues.

Comment: Works fine, except if you have page edit.php?post_type=book&page=custom_page - this  gaves you error...

Answer (score 0):

this code is worked for me

```
/**
 *  Fix Disable add new cpt post (post-new.php?post_type=) - craete_posts
 */

function disable_create_newpost()
{
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if (is_admin() && !empty($typenow) && !empty($pagenow) && $pagenow === 'edit.php' && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'edit.php') && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'post_type=' . $typenow)) {
        $pagenow = 'edit-' . $typenow . '.php';
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_create_newpost');


// END PART
```

thanks for @ggedde